# An item renderer with autosize

Tags: apache-flex

For example, I've created 2 horizontal lists with different heights: 50px and 100px.
I'd like to use 1 item renderer to display both.

The item renderer has to create square items, so it has to produce 50x50 items for the first list and 100x100 items for the second one.

How should I set up the item renderer to get the result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is always the parents responsibility to size it's children.  In this case, the list is the parent and the itemRenderer is the child. The best you can do is offer suggestions in the way of measuredWidth and measuredHeight.

So, you could override the measure method of your itemRenderer component to set the values (50x50 or 100x100) based on some criteria.  But, what would that criteria be??  We don't know because it wasn't provided inyour question.  In an ideal world, it cannot be the height or width of the List; because the itemRenderer should know nothing about the list.

Ignoring the itemRenderer for a moment...

In an MX List, you can use the [rowHeight](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/controls/listClasses/ListBase.html#rowHeight) property.

In a Spark List, you can set the [rowHeight](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/layouts/VerticalLayout.html#rowHeight) property on the List's layout.

You may be able to use a [typicalItem](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/SkinnableDataContainer.html#typicalItem) on the List class instance.

I think these approaches are more likely to give you the results you want than doing something in the itemRenderer.